# Cannot hide Envelope ID on document

Tags: docusignapi

(Using the [Laravel wrapper](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-laravel) for the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-client))

I want to hide the envelope ID on my documents but I don't see how to do it. I tried the following methods:

First I was going to disable the "Include Envelope ID by default", but I found out that it was not checked and it is as a non-editable field.

[image]

Then I tried disabling it programatically with both setting the property 'envelopeIdStamping' when instantiating the EnvelopeDefinition object and using the setEnvelopeIdStamping() method of the resulting object.

```
$envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
    'composite_templates' => $composite_templates,  
    'email_subject' => "Please sign",  //toDo custom title
    'status' => "sent",
    'envelopeIdStamping' => "false",
]);

$envelope_definition->setEnvelopeIdStamping(false);
```

Nothing has succeeded, the document shows the envelope ID anyway, partly covering the barcode of my documents.

Answer (score 1):

The option for envelope ID stamping needs to be enabled on the account so that you can enable 'Enable including the Envelope ID on the document' and disable 'Include Envelope ID by default'. You'll need to create a case with DocuSign support to have the setting enabled - you can open a case here: https://support.docusign.com/s/?language=en_US